# Python; number of days from date

Tags: python, json, date, datetime, calendar

I have a json file that has a date object. its in this format: u'2013-08-29'. I want to find the days between this date and the current date. I have tried:

```
>>> date=data2[u'emd'][u'result'][0][u'row'][u'date']; %%date=u'2013-07-31'
str(datetime.date.today())-str(date)
```

but this didn't work at all. Is there a simple way to do this??

Comment: You're subtracting two strings. How did you expect that to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `datetime` class for parsing the string you got from json file, and for getting the current date. When you subtract those two `datetime` objects, you will get a `timedelta` object that has an attribute `days`.

```
 >>> from datetime import datetime
 >>> (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime('2013-07-31', '%Y-%m-%d')).days
 29
```

Comment: thats almost perfect. but how do i access the number of days as an integer?
...
nevermind :P

Comment: @user2729910 It is an integer. The `days` attribute is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

starting from retrieving field from `data.json` file

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    date = data["masks"]
    (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')).days
```

where using `datetime` as Viktor provided.